# Reinstalling core / stock messaging app on android 4.0

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have got samsung galaxy nexus running ice cream sandwich (android 4.0).

I accidentally uninstalled the core messaging app on my phone and no longer have the stock messaging app. Is there anyway I can reinstall it without resetting my phone?

Please advise.

Answer (score 4):

Since you were able to remove a system app, I assume that your Galaxy Nexus is rooted. Depending which ROM you are running, you should be able to download a copy of that ROM, extract the "Mms.apk" from system/app subfolder within the zip, and then push it via ADB to the same location on the phone. (For stock ROM you might also need Mms.odex file from same location.)

```
adb remount  
adb push C:\path\to\file\Mms.apk /system/app/Mms.apk
```

Comment: I have been trying to get a copy of the ROM with limited success.. my phone system settings indicate that my build number is ICL53F and kernel version is 3.0.8-gaaa2611.. how do I get the ROM??? thanks for your help..

Comment: @Mahesh Have you ever installed a custom ROM (e.g. CyanogenMod, MIUI, etc.) on your Galaxy Nexus?

Comment: No, not yet.. i am using the default rom that the phone was shipped with by vodafone uk